Most Effective Methods to Master Reverse Engineering
I am excited to begin learning assembly. I intend to learn it to guarantee security assurances when writing code for cryptography. One of the skills I wish to gain are reverse engineering.
This is a way to test if I understand the disassembly of code. I came up with a technique to check if my reverse engineered code is correct.
You all heard of competitive programming websites such as LeetCode where you can submit code and an online judge checks if thr code is correct.
What I can do is download someone else's solution in a high level language such as C or Rust. I can compile that to machine code.
Next I can try reverse engineering the machine code back to the source code language and submit that solution to the online judge. If all test cases pass then I reverse engineered correctly.
Please let me know what educational flaws are in this approach.
Thanks!

your "technique" relies on some hypothetical "online judge", but where do you find one?

To be honest...I was planning on reversing LeetCode solutions back into C and submitting to LeetCode. This tests if the reversed code is correct.
